# Background images and Logos

Tags: html, css, background-image

Ok so I have a **Background** background-image: url('images/body.png'); now I want to overlay a *Logo* using background-image: url('images/logo.png'); but the *Logo* is behind the  **Background**. I've tried z-index. But it doesn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post a small fragment of the html structure?

Comment: Background
body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 line-height: 1.5em;
 background-image:url('images/body.jpg');
 z-index: 0;
}
Logo
.logo {
 background-image: url('images/logo.png');
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 z-index: 2;
 position:absolute;
 left:10px;
 top:10px;
}

Comment: The actual HTML would help as well. The CSS is only 1/2 the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a separate div for the logo and use position:absolute. make sure the logo div appears below the div with the /images/body.png  in the page.